# I have set from Agents theme yet the database doesn't contain my set

Tags: set-identification, theme

[image]
I started to sort my LEGO when I realized that I still have most of one of the set I bought so I tried to search the net for the set name. However, the database of LEGO wiki and BrickSet didn't have anything resembling my set. I have come here to get help from any LEGO experts to identify my LEGO set. I am almost 100% sure that it's not a fake LEGO set.

Comment: Ok - welcome. Please post a pic and we can help.

Comment: wow that was fast the pictures up its really hard to find it on the net

Comment: As a heads up, that front minifigure is from EXO Force, not Agents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is part of [8631-1: Jetpack Pursuit](http://brickset.com/sets/8631-1/Jetpack-Pursuit)

[image]